# kernel panic on proxmox 4.4

Tags: kernel, panic, proxmox

I have recently upgraded my proxmox host from 3.3 to 4.4 and now the OS is not booting and it gives me a kernel panic error. I use a dedicated server from [host.ag](https://www.host.ag)

[image]

How do I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Reboot your server and hit **e** key while your server tries to boot and displays the grub menu. This permits you to edit the booting menu (grub) and you can select the other old kernel and boot your server. Then you can investigate and see what went wrong. You could also try a apt-get dist-upgrade and see if there were any packages kept back and not installed correctly. If running apt-get dist-upgrade results in any new packages installed then try rebooting your server again and see if this time boots.

Promox kernel 4.x works just fine on my server:

```
root@pve1:~# uname -a
Linux pve1 4.4.35-2-pve #1 SMP Fri Jan 20 13:58:17 CET 2017 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```